# Texture Analysis using Local Binary Patterns (faces module)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Problem;
Since I didn't find an implementation of LBP in the OpenCV lib, I added the faces module to my OpenCV build. Which does have a LBP implementation.

I'm trying to do texture analysis using local binary patterns (lbp) to determine what is road and what are lines and what isn't road. So I divided my problem up in 3 'labels'. (Road / Lines / The rest )

After that I took 3 random sample images and made subimages with these labels. In other words I selected the road, lines, all the rest and used this as input for the training.

Training:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    Mat trainingData = imread(names[i]), output;

    if (!trainingData.empty()) {

        cvtColor(trainingData, output, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        int pos = names[i].find_last_of('_');
        cv::String l = names[i].substr(pos + 1, 1);
        const char *sub = l.c_str();
        int label = atoi(sub);

        grayscaleImages.push_back(output);
        labels.push_back(label);
    }
}

Ptr<LBPHFaceRecognizer> lbp = createLBPHFaceRecognizer(2, 4, 10, 10);
lbp->train(grayscaleImages, labels);
```

Using LBP to predict:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.images.size(); i++) {

    Mat image = (dataset.images[i]).clone();
    Mat original = image.clone();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < image.size().width; i += squareSize) {
        for (int j = image.size().height / 2 ; j < image.size().height; j += squareSize) {
            Mat subImage = image(Range(j, j + squareSize), Range(i, i + squareSize));

            subImage = applySobel(subImage);    
            int predict = lbp->predict(subImage);
            }
    }

    imshow("Image", original);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

My question is why this isn't working? I'm kinda puzzeled about the prediction aswell. It doesn't seem to be anywhere near close to what I want it to do?

Do I have the implement LBP myself? Does the LBP implementation of the faces module do something special?

Do you have any suggestion on other methods for texture analysis specifically for the case of road / no road?

So here is a general overview of the files I'm using.

Input:
[image: Input]

Selecting our training data:
[image: Selecting training data]

Results of selecting: (every file has a _number to specify the label)
[image: Result of training data]

Final result after training on a random image of the same set. Purple represents road, green is line (or road marking).
[image: Results of LBP predict after training on image]